# apache proxy installation

Tags: apache-2.2, sles, http-proxy

I am having problem installing the proxy_html for apache on an OpenSuse.

It looks like the module is installed:

```
a2enmod proxy_html
"proxy_html" already present
```

and in /etc/sysconfig/apache2 I have the line:

```
APACHE_MODULES="actions alias auth_basic authn_file authz_host authz_groupfile authz_default authz_user autoindex cgi dir env expires include log_config mime negotiation setenvif ssl userdir php5 jk proxy proxy_html rewrite"
```

but apache cannot see the module:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 configtest
Module "proxy_html" is not installed, ignoring.
Check the APACHE_MODULES setting in /etc/sysconfig/apache2.
Syntax OK
```

Any hints or pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to `/usr/share/doc/packages/apache2-mod_proxy_html/README.SuSE` on how to use proxy_html. More information is available in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/mod_proxy_html.conf.in` file. Ensure the order of loaded modules.